# Must CRD version migration work both ways?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-custom-resources

I develop a component that utilises CRDs and is available in two versions - v1 and v2. It is possible to create a v2 resource based on v1 definition but it cannot be done the opposite way. V2 just drops some fields since they are not required anymore. I've developed a web hook to automatically convert existing resources. Conversion is defined as follows in crd definition:

```yaml
conversion:
  strategy: Webhook
  webhook:
    conversionReviewVersions: ["v1", "v2"]
    clientConfig:
      service:
        namespace: fancy-project
        name: conversion-webhook
        path: /crdconvert
```

v2 version is defined as `served` and `storage` whereas v1 only as `served`. My conversion webhook returns with success when it is queried about conversion from v1 to v2 but fails when a request of conversion from v2 to v1 is made. When I try to create a new resource using v1 definition I see an error stating that `from server for: "v1resource.yml": conversion webhook for component/v2, Kind=Proponent failed: Incompatible conversion`. In logs I saw that Kubernetes queried my hook in order to convert from v2 to v1 and before that it requested conversion from v1 to v2. When I issue creation of v2 resource directly everything works fine. Why Kubernetes converts a resource to v2 first and then tries to downgrade it? Do versions of crds must be compatible with each other?

Note that when I allow the conversion from v2 to v1 and use some dummy fields to fill the definition everything starts to work as expected. It means that a v1 resource is created and then migrated to v2

Version:

```
Client Version: 4.6.32
Server Version: 4.6.32
Kubernetes Version: v1.19.0+d670f74
```